# How to compute dot product between each row of two pandas columns with sparse vectors

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix, dot-product

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns each of which contains a SciPy sparse vector in every row. Those vectors are rows from csr matrices (so they are actually matrices of shape 1x8500).

I need to create another column which should contain in each of its rows a dot product between the vectors from the first two columns of the same row.

I know how to do this with `apply` / `map` on each row, but it takes so long when I'm working on datasets with millions of rows. Is there a much faster way to do this on the entire dataframe?

Apart from dot product I will also need to compute cosine similarity but that may be derived from dot products as far as I understand.

Update: I cannot share the actual data here, but here's a toy example (note that I only have the resulting dataframe for now):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
mat = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [mat.getrow(i) for i in range(3)],
                   'Col_2': [mat.getrow(i)*2 for i in range(3)]})
```

I know I could do something like this to calculate the dot product:

```
df['Col_3'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.dot(row['Col_1'],
                       row['Col_2'].transpose()).toarray()[0][0], axis=1)
```

But is there a much more efficient way to calculate that `Col_3`?

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible sample data set and a desired data set?

Comment: Just to be clear: are the items in your dataframe really sparse vectors? Something tells me that's suboptimal design. Do you really need to bring pandas into the picture?

Comment: How big are your datasets?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Strictly speaking they are sparse matrices (csr) containing just one row and around 8500 columns. I try to work with pandas because custom code would need more testing.

Comment: @WR They are tens of millions of rows. Using `apply` and `np.dot` on these structures makes me wait for tens of minutes.

Comment: I'm very familiar with `csr` matrices, and a nodding acquaintance with pandas. 
 sparse dataframes/series. Demonstrate how you construct your dataframe (with  a small example I can copy-n-paste).  I need a clearer sense of what it means for a column to contain a sparse matrix.

Comment: I first thought each of your two columns contains values from a sparse matrix, one number per row per column.  But on further read is sounds like the columns are object dtype, and each cell is a large sparse matrix.  That's the only way a `dot` product makes sense.  In which case you are iterating on rows, and doing `A[i]*B[i].T` (or `np.dot(A[i],B[i].T)`)

Comment: @MaxU I cannot provide any of the actual data, but I added a small example.

Comment: @hpaulj I just updated my question with a toy example.

Comment: @SergeyZakharov, could you post an output of `print(df.dtypes)` and `print(type(df.iloc[0,0]))`?

Comment: Try this: `df['Col_3'] = df['Col_1'].values.dot(df['Col_2'].values)`

Comment: @MaxU this raises `ValueError: dimension mismatch`

Comment: @SergeyZakharov, i think we would need a __reproducible__ data sets in order to be able to help you.

Comment: @MaxU The output for `print(df.dtypes)` is `object` for both columns. The output for `print(type(df.iloc[0,0]))` is `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`.

Comment: @MaxU the one I gave as an update/edit to my question **is** reproducible. You can easily reproduce it by copy/paste into your python environment. I just did so, it works.

Comment: @SergeyZakharov, wow! each __cell__ of your DF is a sparse array?!? I guess it's going to be painful to work with such a data structure... Can't you produce 3D SparseArray instead?

Comment: @MaxU Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @SergeyZakharov, Pandas is not designed to work with such data structures where you are trying to put complex objects (sparse arrays in your case) in each cell. It's like storing a table in each table row in the RDBMS wolrd. You are going to lose the main Pandas power - fast vectorized operations.

Comment: @MaxU Understood. Will try to rebuild my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

With your example

```
matA = mat
matB = mat*2
col3 = (matA.multiply(matB)).sum(axis=1)

[[ 10]
 [ 18]
 [154]]

for i in range(3):
    print(df['Col_1'][i].A, df['Col_2'][i].A)
[[1 0 2]] [[2 0 4]]
[[0 0 3]] [[0 0 6]]
[[4 5 6]] [[ 8 10 12]]
```

`df['Col_1']` dtype is object, and each element is a `csr` matrix, the result of `mat.getrow(i)`.  The display is a little messy with embedded tabs and newline.  The dense equivalent produced with `.A` is prettier.  Shape is consistent, but the number of nonzero terms varies.

Comment: I cannot use this since I don't have any matrices. All I have is those two columns `Col_1` and `Col_2`. And the dataframe of course.

Comment: So far I"m just trying clarify the action.  Constructing multirow sparse matrices from these pandas columns is probably just as much work as performing the `dot` pair by pair.  Once you split things into object arrays, in numpy or pandas, you loose most of the speed of true numeric arrays.